# Datapower B2B transaction viewer

Tags: ibm-datapower

Want to resend selected transaction id from b2b transaction viewer by hitting soap request mentioning only transaction id’s....

IBM says we can extract b2b metadata from b2b query metadata operation....any way using it we can resend transactions 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.1.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/b2bviewer_exportmetadatasoma.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without an external copy of the payload. The b2b-query-metadata does not include payload, only meta-data.
The B2B Archive will contain any payload but that has to be exported and un-zipped first and then you'd have to dig out the original message.

There is a "Resend" of course in the Web Console for the B2B Transaction Viewer but there you can only resend manually.